# MS Office 2016 Standard MAK product key migration

Tags: microsoft-office-2016, license-key

Office 2016 Standard MAK Keys reached to its maximum limit , so we want to remove one of our activated MS Office 2016 Product key  and move it to the another PC with the un-activated MS Office 2016 .

Comment: Did you use `MAK Independent Activation` or `MAK Proxy Activation`?  In any event there isn't a way to "deactivate" Microsoft Office, what you have to do is "reactivated" every installation you do want, but there are normally minimum number of clients in order to do that.  You have not supplied enough information in order to answer your question.

Comment: we have only single product key for 100 licenses , so we put product key and then an activation wizard is appear that routes it towards the internet for activation.

Comment: That does not answer my question about which activation method you used.  I suppose it does not matter, in either event, you have to call the activation center in order to "reactivate" the installations you actually want.  The fact you use "the internet" for activation, indicates you used `MAK Independent Activation` by the way.  I do realize that my statement about deactivation was slightly incorrect, but were not talking about Office 365, so the web interface isn't applicable.

Comment: yes i confirmed it we use MAK Independent Activation @Ramhound

Comment: So you should uninstall the product from the machine in question, install it on the new machine, then activate the new machine by calling the [Microsoft Activation Center](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/-telephone-activation-is-no-longer-supported-for-your-product-error-when-activating-office-9b016cd2-0811-4cb3-b896-5a6a13177713?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).  Link has been provided to determine which number you should use.  Otherwise the answer you received would have been more or less what I was going to submit as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately a MAK key has a certain number of activations associated with it.  Once you use them up, they are gone. However, MAK has been designed with this scenario in mind.

Once you approach your maximum number of activations, the number of activations will automatically increase by a little bit to give you some buffer, up to a certain extent.

If you have even used this extent, you have no choice but to
call the [Microsoft Activation Call Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/existing-customer/activation-centers.aspx), choose Open License then Other reason.

Explain why you want your MAK increase and give your Parent Open ID and Open License, and they will add some more activations.

However, you should examine your procedures and see why you have overused
your MAK activations.